# Split graphics larger than page size to multiple pages

Tags: c#, pdf, graphics, pdfsharp

I am using Pdfsharp 1.32.3057 to draw graphics (some paths). It might happen, that these graphics are larger than the final print format (A4 page format). 
Therefore I want to split graphics larger than the final print format to multiple pages. I also want to include some marker on where one could cut off margins of the printed pages using scissors and then align them next to each other so they apppear like one large page and the graphic becomes complete.

Any idea on how I could realize this splitting?
Thanks for any hint on this!

Answer (score 0):

What I would do: draw the graphics on an XForm with the size you need for the graphics.

Then draw chunks of that XForm on the page with the size and offset you need (offset will be negative for second+ row and second+ column.
Then draw four white rectangles over of the image borders if you want to have borders. Draw your markers/scissors over the rectangles.

This way you will draw the same XForm on all pages. PDFsharp will include a single instance of the XForm in the PDF file. You can also add a page that shows the complete image - this will add few bytes only to the PDF file and will be more comfortable for those watching on the screen and for those who can do with a shrunk single-page printout.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply! I got your idea, but how would you realize the offsets? My first idea would be XGraphics.TranslateTransform, would you agree on this?

Comment: Why so complicated? You can call overloads of DrawImage() with several parameters, including position and size.

Comment: Either my knowledge of pdfsharp isn't yet sufficient or you mean something different - I am creating my own XGraphics using e.g. XGraphics.DrawPath. I am not loading an image. So to my knowledge DrawImage() is not applicable. Please let me know, should it be possible to use DrawImage in my case.

Comment: Shame on me, didn't read the question properly - but still it can be done using XForms. See the sample code on the site: http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/XForms-sample.ashx  You can create an XForm of the size you need and then use DrawImage() to draw chunks of it on PDF pages of standard size.

Comment: Thanks again, first offset tests using XForm look promising! I currently have one problem though: Imagine my XForm was created with a size of 40 cm x 40 cm. The graphics drawn on it however only use 5 cm x 5 cm. The 5 cm x 5 cm graphic would obviously fit on one A4 page, while the 40 cm x 40 cm XForm does not. How can I find out the effectively used space of the XForm? (Use case: think of a method doing the distribution over pages and receiving only the pdfDocument and XForm as parameters) Do you have any idea on this?